# Adding a value to DataGrid ComboBox during runtime. The value should not be part of combobox list

Tags: c#

I'm trying to add a value to combo box in data grid view table, during run time. First I have added items to the combo box. During run time I am trying to add the data from a datatable to the data grid. If the data is not part of combo box item, it is not accepting. I want it to accept the value and display it in the grid, though it is not part of combobox. See the code sample, which I am trying below:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dt.Columns.Add("FieldName");
            dt.Columns.Add("Value");
            dt.Columns.Add("Flags");
            dt.Rows.Add("Field1", "Value1", "#A");
            dt.Rows.Add("Field2", "Value2", "#B");
            dt.Rows.Add("Field3", "Value3", "#C");
            dt.Rows.Add("Field4", "Value4", "#D");
            dt.Rows.Add("Field5", "Value5", "#E");

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                string fieldName = Convert.ToString(dr["FieldName"]);
                string value = Convert.ToString(dr["Value"].ToString());
                string flags = Convert.ToString(dr["Flags"].ToString());
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(fieldName, value, flags);
            }

            ComboBox cb = new ComboBox();
            AddListComboBox(ref cb);
            ((DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)dataGridView1.Columns["Flags"]).DataSource = cb.Items;

        }

        DataTable csvDataTable = new DataTable();
        public DataTable defaultFlagsDataTable()
        {
            //Create default flags datatable
            if (csvDataTable.Rows.Count <= 0)
            {
                csvDataTable.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
                csvDataTable.Columns.Add("Description", typeof(string));
                csvDataTable.Columns.Add("Obsolete", typeof(bool));
                csvDataTable.Columns.Add("Color", typeof(string));
            }

            //Add default flags to datatable
            csvDataTable.Rows.Add("#A", "Asset Data", false, 13168840);
            csvDataTable.Rows.Add("#B", "System Default", false, 15780518);
            csvDataTable.Rows.Add("#C", "Data From GeoPlan", false, 65280);
            csvDataTable.Rows.Add("#D", "Model Import", false, 3981040);
            csvDataTable.Rows.Add("#E", "System Calculated", false, 3981040);
            //csvDataTable.Rows.Add("#F", "CSV Import", false, 33023);

            return csvDataTable;
        }

        public void AddListComboBox(ref ComboBox CB)
        {
            defaultFlagsDataTable();
            foreach (DataRow dr in csvDataTable.Rows)
            {
                string flags = dr["Name"].ToString();
                CB.Items.Add(flags);
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Does any one know the solution for this

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your combobox value is bound to the datagrid, then this cannot work.  The items in your combobox have to contain all possible values that could be in the database field.  This is akin to an enumeration.  In such cases I usually have a separate 'Options' table in the database listing all the options (usually in id, description format) and then impose a foreign key restriction on the main table.  Then instead of manually creating a list in code, I read the contents of the options table into a DataTable and make that the DataSource of the ComboBox.